# How do I redirect a user on registration to a specific node?

Tags: 8, users, redirection

I want to redirect a user when they log in to `node/2`.  In Drupal 7, this is just `drupal_goto()`, but [that was removed from 8](https://www.drupal.org/node/2023537).  This is what I tried:

```
function mymodule_form_user_register_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $form_state->setRedirect('node/2');
}
```

I'm not getting an error but I'm not getting redirected, either.

EDIT: Then, based on Berdir's comments, I tried this:

```
function mymodule_form_user_register_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['#submit'][] = 'mymodule_user_register_submit_handler';
}

function mymodule_user_register_submit_handler($form, &$form_state) {
  $form_state->setRedirect('entity.node.canonical', ['node' => 2]);
}
```

However, this gives me an integrity error:

```
Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '16-0-0-ja' for key 'PRIMARY': INSERT INTO {user__field_agree} (entity_id, revision_id, bundle, delta, langcode, field_agree_value) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1, :db_insert_placeholder_2, :db_insert_placeholder_3, :db_insert_placeholder_4, :db_insert_placeholder_5); Array ( [:db_insert_placeholder_0] => 16 [:db_insert_placeholder_1] => 16 [:db_insert_placeholder_2] => user [:db_insert_placeholder_3] => 0 [:db_insert_placeholder_4] => ja [:db_insert_placeholder_5] => 1 ) in Drupal\Core\Entity\Sql\SqlContentEntityStorage->save() (line 757 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/Sql/SqlContentEntityStorage.php).
Drupal\Core\Database\Statement->execute(Array, Array)
Drupal\Core\Database\Connection->query('INSERT INTO {user__field_agree} (entity_id, revision_id, bundle, delta, langcode, field_agree_value) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1, :db_insert_placeholder_2, :db_insert_placeholder_3, :db_insert_placeholder_4, :db_insert_placeholder_5)', Array, Array)
Drupal\Core\Database\Driver\mysql\Connection->query('INSERT INTO {user__field_agree} (entity_id, revision_id, bundle, delta, langcode, field_agree_value) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1, :db_insert_placeholder_2, :db_insert_placeholder_3, :db_insert_placeholder_4, :db_insert_placeholder_5)', Array, Array)
Drupal\Core\Database\Driver\mysql\Insert->execute()
Drupal\Core\Entity\Sql\SqlContentEntityStorage->saveToDedicatedTables(Object, , Array)
Drupal\Core\Entity\Sql\SqlContentEntityStorage->doSaveFieldItems(Object, Array)
Drupal\user\UserStorage->doSaveFieldItems(Object)
Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityStorageBase->doSave(NULL, Object)
Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageBase->save(Object)
Drupal\Core\Entity\Sql\SqlContentEntityStorage->save(Object)
Drupal\Core\Entity\Entity->save()
Drupal\user\RegisterForm->save(Array, Object)
call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
Drupal\Core\Form\FormSubmitter->executeSubmitHandlers(Array, Object)
Drupal\Core\Form\FormSubmitter->doSubmitForm(Array, Object)
Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder->processForm('user_register_form', Array, Object)
Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder->buildForm(Object, Object)
Drupal\Core\Controller\FormController->getContentResult(Object, Object)
call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\{closure}()
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->executeInRenderContext(Object, Object)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->wrapControllerExecutionInRenderContext(Array, Array)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\{closure}()
call_user_func_array(Object, Array)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(Object, 1)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle(Object, 1, 1)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle(Object, 1, 1)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->pass(Object, 1, 1)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->handle(Object, 1, 1)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1)
Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1)
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object)
```

Comment: This could also be accomplished using [Rules 8](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules)

Comment: @NoSssweat Yes, I can't wait till Rules is marked stable for D8.

Comment: you can do it with the latest 8.x-3.0-unstable7 version, **[see my demo](https://r0f2j.ply.st/user/login)**, but if you want to wait for a stable version, I understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Redirection can be set in a submit handler.

```
function mymodule_user_register_submit_handler($form, &$form_state) {
  $form_state->setRedirect('entity.node.canonical', ['node' => 2]);
}
```

But the new submit handler should be appended to the submit button's '#submit' value, not the form's root '#submit'.

```
function mymodule_form_user_register_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'mymodule_user_register_submit_handler';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

So like you I tried Berdir's answer in about every different way possible. For some reason the using the mymodule_form_user_register_form_alter hook did not work, but the mymodule_form_alter hook with a conditional did like:

```
function mymodule_user_register_custom_submit_handler($form, 
FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $form_state->setRedirect('entity.node.canonical', ['node' => 1]);
}
function mymodule_form_alter(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, 
$form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'user_register_form') {
    $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'mymodule_user_register_custom_submit_handler';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use setRedirect() in form alter, that hasn't changed compared to Drupal 7. That would send the user away *while* building/displaying the form.

Just like in Drupal 7, you need to add an additional submit callback and then set the redirect *there*.

Also note that that setRedirect() expects a route name and arguments, not a path. In your case, that would be `$form_state->setRedirect('entity.node.canonical', ['node' => 2]));` or `$form_state->setRedirectUrl($node->toUrl())`.

Comment: I tried adding a callback, but I'm getting a duplicate insert error.  Is there some trick to that?